# How to get Place Details Responses from Google Place API or SimpleGeo in chinese?

Tags: php, google-api, multilingual, simplegeo

I am using SimpleGeo for business places for my iPhone, 
simply

The Flow is 
iPhone --> PHP page --> --> SimpleGeo server.
SimpleGeo Server response --> PHP page --> iPhone.

when Language of my iPhone is Chinese, then I want return data from SimpleGeo in chinese, how Can I?

the response of SimpleGeo is in English, so I want response in chinese, is there any way to do so, if not than any other possibility using Google Places API for chinese response from server?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if SimpleGeo provides Places results in Chinese, but the Google Places API does.

It's just a parameter that you specify in order to return the results back in Chinese.

> Certain parameters are required to initiate a Place Search request. As
>   is standard in URLs, all parameters are separated using the ampersand
>   (&) character. The list of parameters and their possible values are
>   enumerated below.
>
> ...
>
> language (optional) — The language code,
>   indicating in which language the results should be returned, if
>   possible. See the list of supported languages and their codes. Note
>   that we often update supported languages so this list may not be
>   exhaustive.

Here's a list of the languages that are supported by the Google Places API https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=p9pdwsai2hDMsLkXsoM05KQ&gid=1